# How can I pass a value from an XML view to the controller?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm practicing data binding with mvc in openUI5. I have an XML view containing a table populated from a JSON model, with a button next to a text field on each row. I want to enter a new Position into the text field, press the button next to it and have the Position column cell update, to demonstrate binding.

```
ID    Name       Age   Position     Update Position
101   Brian Cox  23    Developer    [text area for new position]   [update button]
```

XML View:

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="view.App"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <Table items="{/employee}">
<columns>
  <Column>
    <Text text="ID" />
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <Text text="Name" />
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <Text text="Age" />
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <Text text="Position" />
  </Column>
  <Column>
    <Text text="Update Position" />
  </Column>
  <Column>
  </Column>
</columns>

<items>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <cells>
      <Text text="{id}" />
      <Text text="{Name}" />
      <Text text="{Age}" />
      <Text text="{Position}"/>
      <TextArea />
      <Button text="Update" press="posUpdate"/>
    </cells>
  </ColumnListItem>
</items>

</Table>
</mvc:View>
```

In my controller, I have a function attached to the button to update the JSONModel of employees.

```
sap.ui.controller("view.App", {

onInit: function(){
    oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("employee.json");
    oModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
},

posUpdate: function(){
    //trying to fetch the value of the textarea in the view
    var data = sap.ui.getCore().byId("newPos").getValue();
    sap.ui.getCore().getModel('oModel').getProperty("Position");
    oModel.setData({Position: data}, true);
}
});
```

JSON:

```
{
"employee": [
    {
        "id": 101,
        "Name": "Brian Cox",
        "Age": "23",
        "Position": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "Name": "Richard Feynman",
        "Age": "66",
        "Position": "HR Clerk"
    },
    {
        "id": 103,
        "Name": "Tycho Brahe",
        "Age": "65",
        "Position": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 104,
        "Name": "Albert Einstein",
        "Age": "32",
        "Position": "Consultant"
    }
 ]
}
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
<title>UI5 MVC with XmlView</title>
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
    src='../resources/sap-ui-core.js'
    data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
    data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m, sap.ui.table'></script>

<script>
    sap.ui.localResources("view");

    var view = new sap.ui.xmlview("App", "view.App").placeAt("content");

</script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the controller posUpdate function, I want to retrieve the value of the text field, and change the Position value in the model to this value. How can I do this for a specific JSON object? I feel I need to change the JSON file somehow to accommodate this.

I am new to UI5 and would also welcome any helpful comments on my code structure and practices in general.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.To get the `TextArea` from each table Row, you need to first get the table Row which is the parent of the `Button`.

2.To get the binding path of the current Row, you can call `getBindingContext()` of Button to get the path.

3.As the default binding mode is TwoWay, you only need to call setProperty and the data will be refresh automatically.

Please read the comment of the following function and i also inserted a working code snippet. Please 
run it to see the results.In case any further questions, please leave a comment.

```
posUpdate: function(oEvent) {
    //get the event source which is the button
    var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
    //get the parent of the button which is row
    var oRow = oButton.getParent();
    //get the textarea which is the fourth of the cells of row
    var oTextArea = oRow.getCells()[4];
    //get the value of the new position
    var sNewPosition = oTextArea.getValue();

    //get the model 
    var oModel = oButton.getModel();
    //get the binding path of current row
    var oPath = oButton.getBindingContext().sPath;
    //set the Postion to the new Position
    oModel.setProperty(oPath + "/Position", sNewPosition);  
}
```

```html
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.viz" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View
        controllerName="view.App"
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns="sap.m">
        <Table items="{/employee}">
      <columns>
        <Column>
          <Text text="ID" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Name" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Age" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Position" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Update Position" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
        </Column>
      </columns>

      <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
          <cells>
            <Text text="{id}" />
            <Text text="{Name}" />
            <Text text="{Age}" />
            <Text text="{Position}"/>
            <TextArea />
            <Button text="Update" press="posUpdate"/>
          </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
      </items>

      </Table>
      </mvc:View>
</script>
  
  
  <script>
    sap.ui.controller("view.App", {

onInit: function(){
    var data = {
"employee": [
    {
        "id": 101,
        "Name": "Brian Cox",
        "Age": "23",
        "Position": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "Name": "Richard Feynman",
        "Age": "66",
        "Position": "HR Clerk"
    },
    {
        "id": 103,
        "Name": "Tycho Brahe",
        "Age": "65",
        "Position": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 104,
        "Name": "Albert Einstein",
        "Age": "32",
        "Position": "Consultant"
    }
 ]
};
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data);
    oModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
},

posUpdate: function(oEvent){
    //get the event source which is the button
    var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
    //get the parent of the button which is row
    var oRow = oButton.getParent();
    //get the textarea which is the fourth of the cells of row
    var oTextArea = oRow.getCells()[4];
    //get the value of the new position
    var sNewPosition = oTextArea.getValue();
    
    //get the model 
    var oModel = oButton.getModel();
    //get the binding path of current row
    var oPath = oButton.getBindingContext().sPath;
    //set the Postion to the new Position
    oModel.setProperty(oPath+"/Position",sNewPosition);
     
}
});
    var myView = sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {
        viewContent: jQuery('#view1').html()
    }); // 
    myView.placeAt('content');
</script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
    <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate binding all you need to do is:

replace:

```
  <TextArea />
```

with

```
<TextArea value="{Position}"/>
```

And remove the Update button completely.

Direct DOM or SAP object manipulation to get the value defies the whole purpose of two way binding frameworks!!!

Allen, 7 lines of code to do the binding??? Please tell me you're joking.